signal rate error handling in FPGA
I am implementing a Manchester decoder for a serial input with rate 10mbps +/- 0.01% bit timing error. The sampling frequency is 160MHz +/- 50ppm.
Longest packet is 1526 bytes * 8 = 12208 bits. So there can be bit sampling error up to 12208 bits * (50ppm + 0.01%) = 12208 * (0.00005 + 0.0001) = 1.8312 bits.
Please suggest me how to handle this timing error. What are the techniques can be used for bit boundaries synchronization.

Have you considered an analog or digital PLL? Adjust 3/4T 7.5 us non-retriggerable  one-shot to gate pulse edge into an XOR mixer and control VCO with a lock detector.

Well, obviously you can't just rely blindly on your raw sample rate. You need to adapt to the timing of the edges you actually see in the signal. Sure, most of them will be 8 or 16 cycles apart, but sometimes they'll be 7/9 or 15/17 cycles, and your decoding state machine needs to allow that.
The output of this decoder will be both a bit value and a "strobe" signal that indicates that you have a valid bit. Normally, this will feed into another state machine that identifies byte boundaries in the stream of bits, and then loads the packet bytes into a FIFO of some sort.

The whole point of the Manchester coding is that you have a clock reference embedded in the data, i.e. a transition in the middle of each bit, which you can use to detect the bit boundaries.
The ideal counts between transition is either 8 clocks between edges for half a bit and 16 clocks between middle positions of two bits, so anything below 12 clocks is a half-bit period and anything above 12 clocks is a full-bit period which can only happen between centers of two bits. Anything above 17 clocks must be an error but feel free to apply more tolerance.
